# Resolve any number promises nested inside of an object

Tags: javascript, object, promise, filereader, traversal

I have an object with nested `File` instances in various locations. I would like to recursively go through the object, check if an object is an `instanceof File`, use a promise to create a data url from the instance, and resolve the promise only when all of the promises have been resolved.

I have an existing functions that returns a Promise and resolves when the data URL from the file is ready.

```
export const parsePhoto = (file) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const reader = new FileReader();

        try {
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);

            reader.onloadend = () => {
                return resolve(reader.result);
            }
        } catch(e) {
            console.warn('Could not upload photo', e.target);
        }
    })
}
```

I have a function to recursively look for a `File` in the object.

```
export const convertPhotosToBase64 = (values) => {
    if (!values) return values;

    const converted = Object.keys(values).reduce((acc, key) => {
        if (values[key] instanceof File) {
            // Do something here
            acc[key] = parsePhoto(values[key]);
        }

        if (isArray(values[key])) {
            acc[key] = values[key].map(value => {
                if (typeof value === 'object' && !isArray(value)) {
                    return convertPhotosToBase64(value);
                }

                return value;
            })
        }

        // Recurse if object
        if (typeof values[key] === 'object' && !isArray(values[key])) {
            acc[key] = convertPhotosToBase64(values[key]);
        }

        return acc;
    }, values);

    return converted;
}
```

I want to keep the existing structure of the object passed (`values`) and only replace the File instances with the base64 string.

I'm also aware of `Promise.all` but unsure how to use it in this context.

**How can I return `convertPhotosToBase64` as a promise that resolves when *all* of the files have been converted to base64 strings?**

Comment: [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

Comment: How would I use `Promise.all` in this instance? I'm aware that `Promise.all` exists.

Comment: You create an array of promises and then `return Promise.all(promiseArray)` from your inner `.then()` handler.

Comment: Do you really need it to be base64?

Comment: I have to store it in a database, so yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's first simplify your function a bit, to reduce the duplication of all those conditions:

```
export function convertPhotosToBase64(value) {
    if (typeof value !== 'object') return value;

    if (value instanceof File) return parsePhoto(value);

    if (isArray(value)) return value.map(convertPhotosToBase64);

    return Object.keys(value).reduce((acc, key) => {
        acc[key] = convertPhotosToBase64(value[key]);
        return acc;
    }, {});
}
```

Now, `parsePhoto` is asynchronous and returns a promise. This means that the whole `convertPhotosToBase64` will need to become asynchronous and always return a promise. Given the four clearly distinct cases, that's actually simpler than it sounds:

```
export function convertPhotosToBase64(value) {
    // wrap value
    if (typeof value !== 'object') return Promise.resolve(value);

    // already a promise
    if (value instanceof File) return parsePhoto(value);

    // map creates all the promises in parallel, use `Promise.all` to await them
    if (isArray(value)) return Promise.all(value.map(convertPhotosToBase64));

    // chain one after the other
    return Object.keys(value).reduce((accP, key) =>
        accP.then(acc =>
            convertPhotosToBase64(value[key]).then(res => {
                acc[key] = res;
                return acc;
            })
        )
    , Promise.resolve({}));
}
```

If you are ok with doing everything in parallel (not only the arrays), you can also simplify the last case to

```
    return Object.keys(value).reduce((accP, key) =>
        Promise.all([accP, convertPhotosToBase64(value[key])]).then([acc, res] => {
            acc[key] = res;
            return acc;
        })
    , Promise.resolve({}));
```

or maybe better

```
    const keys = Object.keys(value);
    return Promise.all(keys.map(key => convertPhotosToBase64(value[key])).then(results => {
        const acc = {};
        for (const [key, i] of keys.entries())
            acc[key] = results[i];
        return acc;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

`Promise.all` does what you want it to. The easiest way to use it in this situation is by doing `return Promise.all(converted)` at the bottom of your function, which will return a special promise that doesn't resolve until all the promises in the argument have resolved.